# Android Crashing on user logout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-activity

I have the following code which is executed once the user clicks a button

```
public void logout(){

        // redirect user back to login screen activity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // start Login Activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

However each time the button is clicked, the emulator crashes. Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error returning from logcat?

Comment: Just a note (unrelated to your crash problem): Calling `i.setFlags()` will clear the flags that you just set with `i.addFlags()`. You need to call `i.addFlags()` twice - or you can just OR the flags together (see @biddulph.r answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was prior to this method being called. I was trying to set the text on an EditText item that was part of another layout

Answer (score 1):

You can set flags instead by doing

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

I doubt this is your issue though, make sure you are calling `startActivity` from within the Activity and the correct `Thread`, and make sure there are no issues with the `onCreate` of your `LoginActivity`.

Is this consistent with more than one emulator? Try a different configuration, and also check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, is the second `Activity` defined?